# Trying to read multiple lines from a one text file then print out results to new text file java

Tags: java, bufferedwriter

I created this program where it takes an input from one text file where students grades and names are recorded like this:

lastName:firstName:Test1:Test2:Test3

After this the program reads them and separates them by a delimiter which is ":". I am stuck on how to get the program to read the next line on the original text file with names. It stops after reading the first line and crashes. Code below.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class exam {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String lastName;
        String firstName;
        int test1;
        int test2;
        int test3;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("output.txt"));

        input.useDelimiter(":");

        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            lastName = input.next();
            firstName = input.next();
            test1 = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
            test2 = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
            test3 = Integer.parseInt(input.next());


            //test print statements
            System.out.println(firstName + " " + lastName);
            System.out.println(test1);
            System.out.println(test2);
            System.out.println(test3);

            //averaging student letter grade

            double overallGrade = (test1 * .25) + (test2 * .30) + (test3 * .45);
            String letterGrade;
            System.out.println(overallGrade);

            //counter for letter grade
            int counterA = 0;
            int counterB = 0;
            int counterC = 0;
            int counterD = 0;
            int counterF = 0;


            if (overallGrade >= 90) {
                letterGrade = "A";
                counterA++;
            } else if (overallGrade >= 80) {
                letterGrade = "B";
                counterB++;
            } else if (overallGrade >= 70) {
                letterGrade = "C";
                counterC++;
            } else if (overallGrade >= 60) {
                letterGrade = "D";
                counterD++;
            } else {
                letterGrade = "F";
                counterF++;
            }

            try {
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("filenamehere"));
                writer.write(lastName + ":" + firstName + ":" + test1 + ":" + test2 + ":" + test3 + ":" + overallGrade + ":" + letterGrade);
                writer.write("\nA " + counterA + "\nB " + counterB + "\nC " + counterC + "\nD " + counterD + "\nF " + counterF);

                writer.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            System.out.println(lastName + " " + firstName + " " + letterGrade);
        }


        input.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens *exactly* when it crashes? What error messages, if any, do you see?

Comment: Myself, I wouldn't change the input Scanner's delimiter, but instead would use the input file-based Scanner object to read each line of the file, basically, `while (input.hasNextLine()) {  String line = input.nextLine(); ... }`, and then split the line received using `String[] tokens = line.split(":");`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels That's a bit bizarre - the delimiter isn't the problem here, and using solely 'nextLine()' in scanner is just not what it was for. That's what BufferedReader is for. Which is probably the better tool here.

Comment: @rzwitserloot `while (input.hasNextLine())` and then never calling `input.nextLine()` is a *bad idea*. Don't intermingle `nextLine()` and `nextFoo()`.

Comment: @rzwitserloot: I'm not sure how bizarre is bizarre, but heck, it seems reasonable to grab each line, and then use another tool to process each line. It could be another Scanner that uses a delimiter based on `":"`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I get the following.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "99
Dear"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
 at exam.main(exam.java:22)

Comment: @ElliottFrischObviously, when I say, don't call nextLine, I imply also not calling hasNextLine. I can't shove an entire answer in an SO comment, and I know you know what I meant. What's with the pedantic snipery on SO lately? Spend the time on writing an answer that helps OP instead perhaps.

Comment: @rzwitserloot: whoa there fella

Answer (score 1):

You've told the scanner that tokens are separated by colons, and then you keep asking for 'what's after the next token'.

The problem is, you told scanner that all input is separated by **a colon**. So, not a newline then. The scanner dutifully reports that the 5th token in this file:

```
lastName:firstName:Test1:Test2:Test3
foobar:baz:1:2:3
```

would be: `"Test3\nfoobar"`. After all, that sequence of characters in between the colons, isn't it? You see how two delimiters are involved here: A newline separates 2 records. Colons separate entries within a record. Scanner is not good at this job. So, don't use it.

Let's first get rid of the obsolete File API and use the new one, then, let's fix your resource leakage by using try-with-resources, which ensures that any resource you open you definitely close (that `close()` call you wrote? It won't be called if exceptions occur, for example). Let's also fix your deplorable error handling (don't ever catch an exception, do `e.printStackTrace()`, and keep on going. That's just nasty - you have no idea what just happened and yet the code will continue? When by definition the system is now in a state you haven't thought of? Not a good idea at all). And, of course, use the right tool for job, BufferedReader: It's a simpler API than scanner that just gets you lines. Which is what you want, and we'll deal with splitting the fields within a single record out on a line-by-line basis:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  try (var in = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("output.txt")) {
    processLine(in);
  }
}

static void processLine(String in) throws IOException {
  String[] parts = in.split(":");
  String lastName = parts[0];
  String firstName = parts[1];
  String test1 = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
  String test2 = Integer.parseInt(parts[3]);
  String test3 = Integer.parseInt(parts[4]);

  // rest of your code goes here
}
```